# IIS Rewrite for number at end of domain after slash

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a script handler (.ashx) in ASP.NET that takes one querystring param ID of an integer.  I would like to further shorten the URL such as:

Current:

https://domain.com/Link.ashx?ID=225
or
https://www.domain.com/Link.ashx?ID=225

TO:

https://domain.com/225

I am not using MVC and suspect I could do this with IIS URL rewriting.  Can anyone help with what the required configuration would need to be to support this?

http://domain.com/225 would redirect to https://domain.com/Link.ashx?ID=225

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
  <rule name="test">
        <match url="^[0-9]+$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="Link.ashx?ID={R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

^ = start with
[0-9] = any number
+ = repeated 1 or more times
$ = ends with

Comment: Thank you, I have to be careful though some other form of the URL doesn't have numbers, i.e. if an incoming URL of https://domain.com/Link.ashx?ID=225 came in then it to would get redirected, or other URL's such as: http://domain.com/?foo=99883&foo2=883773&r=00992.

Comment: No, this will only match numbers. So /1 /123 /1234 will all match but /1a /a1 /12345r /?foo=99883etc or any other non number will not match